# Hindi Fonts not Displaying at bRowser

Tags: php

I am Copying Hindi Words From Google Translator and Pasting it in my php page. In editor It is Correctly displaying But at Browser it is showing "???/" Marks. I have included charset"utf-8" in header also.

Comment: see if your browser supports hindi font??

Comment: What encoding are you saving the file in?

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>



<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="hi">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

</head>
<body>


      <span>मैं एक अच्छा प्रोग्रामर हूँ</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Copy this and Save this in one html file..and try to run..it'll work..

Comment: hmm... really liking the sentence you wrote in hindi :)

Comment: Hi Rajat, am fetching Hindi language data from db and echoing it on simple *.php file with all above meta tag + my db props `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci` but no luck, still getting garbage characters like "??? ??? ???". But above span tag appearing in proper Hindi. So, help me about fetching db data.

Comment: @Frank u mean the span when copied in yr php page show properly?? and check if the table you are using has stored data in utf-8..u can check in phpmyadmin..and is the data getting shown in proper hindi in phpmyadmin??

Comment: I did it through `mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf8');` an additional research on connection encoding. Thanks for help.